# How to set unloaddelay of embedded tomcat standardcontext in context.xml file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat

According to the tomcat official [document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html), I know that there is a attribute `unloadDelay`. And I have configured it in a Programmatic way like this in a spring-boot application.

```
    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedWebApplicationContext embeddedContext;

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer cookieProcessorCustomizer() {
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
                if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                    ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                            .addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {

                        @Override
                        public void customize(Context context) {
                            StandardContext standardContext=(StandardContext)context;
                            standardContext.setUnloadDelay(20000); 

                        }

                    });
                }
            }

        };
    }
```

My question is how to customize `unloadDelay` in a file like context.xml instead of writing such a piece of code.

Comment: Do you mean how to change it at runtime or how to write a `context.xml`. The `context.xml` file is covered extensively in the link you provided.

Comment: @AdamGent Thank you. I'd like to do both. Change it at runtime via something like endpoints and set a initial value via context.xml.